# Interface as ServiceStack Razor Model

Tags: .net, razor, servicestack

I am relatively new to ServiceStack, but I love what I see so far. However I've come up against a wall on this one -

This is what my razor template looks like -

```
@inherits ViewPage<IChallenge>

@{
    foreach (var codeFile in Model.CodeFiles)
    {
//do something here
    }
}
```

here, IChallenge is an interface, and the service dynamically selects a given implementation of this interface while returning. The service is wired to return Interface itself as so -

```
public class WebChallenge : IReturn<IChallenge> { /* properties */ }
```

However I get the following error when I run the code -

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceStack.Razor.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' to 'IChallenge'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

with this as the response with the full stack -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Challenge1Response xmlns="" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ResponseStatus> 
<ErrorCode>RuntimeBinderException</ErrorCode> 
<Message>Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceStack.Razor.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' to 'CodeGuru.Exercises.IChallenge'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)</Message> 
<StackTrace> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) 
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0) 
at ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateBase`1.get_Model() 
at CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.faaccadc.Execute() 
at ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateService.ExecuteTemplate[T](T model, String name, String defaultTemplatePath, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) 
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ExecuteTemplate[T](T model, String name, String templatePath, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) 
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ProcessRazorPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, ViewPageRef razorPage, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes) 
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object dto) 
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;SerializeToStream&gt;b__0(IViewEngine x) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) 
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, IHttpResponse httpRes) 
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
</StackTrace> 
</ResponseStatus> 
</Challenge1Response>
```

This error disappears if I use a specific implementation - however I need to be able to send any implementation selected at runtime. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that if the Interface is wrapped as a property of another strongly typed object, and that object is used as the model in the view, it works fine and I can access the Interface properties as well. This could be a work-around but I'd like to know if someone knows a better answer, since this feels like jumping through hoops.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried an abstract base class, or just a base class, instead of the interface

public abstract class Challenge : IChallenge

{
}

public class WebChallenge : Challenge, IReturn

{
}

then in the razor

@inherits ViewPage

Comment: I haven't tried it, but again it feels more like a work-around - I want to know how to make a simple interface work as a Model for a view.